# Beyond Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, editors

I'm using **Overleaf**, but unfortunately it doesn't support too big projects (e.g. books with several hundreds of pages, or books with too figures, tikzpictures, pgfplots... ). In your opinion what is the best way to solve my problem? I mean: Is it better to switch to other built-in LaTeX editors (e.g. Emacs or [these others](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)) or something else?
I know that in Overleaf is it possible to pay 21,96$ per month in order to have illimitate projects and some other advantage.
Thank you so much

Comment: It's your choice, we can't tell what's best for you...

Comment: However, a piece of advice wouldn't hurt me

Comment: If you haven't used latex on your own pc before I'd probably go with texstudio. So editors like emacs (which I use) has many useful features, but the learning curve is very steep. Also don't forget that the editor is one part, you still need to install latex as well

Comment: I start with vim already, so no overleaf. You can try using local editor, then if it gets inconvenient switch to paying

Comment: To the answers of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/219947), you will find features, pros and cons of many LaTeX editors/IDEs.

Comment: GNU Emacs all the time, invest a week or so to learn the basics, but later you will enjoy an editor for life. :-)

Comment: Also if you just need it for the "compilation", note that you don't actually need ANY editor/IDE. Just install a full distribution of LaTeX and compile using your terminal, e.g., `pdflatex myproject`. Of course you can make trivial changes using GNU nano or default text editors available in your distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overleaf is a very nice introduction to LaTeX, and I invite my students to use it, but when you get to the point where your needs become important, I strongly suggest to leave behind online solutions that you don't fully control.

Install a full version TeX Live with the editor of your choice (I'd suggest TeXstudio by default, or VS Code if you're an experienced coder), and you'll be fine.

It's free forever and you'll have more options than Overleaf can ever provide, including a superior editor.